# Intel 10Gb 82599ES has no carrier

Tags: linux, networking, drivers

I am unable to get my `Intel 10Gbit/s 82599ES` NIC running. Neither on Kernel 4.19:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4.19.0-8-amd64
```

with built-in driver:

```
$ sudo ethtool -i eth6
driver: ixgbe
version: 5.1.0-k
firmware-version: 0x80000827, 16.5.19
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

nor on Kernel 5.6:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 5.6.0-2-amd64
```

with the latest driver:

```
$ sudo ethtool -i eth6
driver: ixgbe
version: 5.7.1
firmware-version: 0x80000827, 16.5.19
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

What I did:

```
$ sudo ip link
8: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:9f:82:92:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`sudo ip link set eth6 up`:

```
$ sudo ip link
8: eth6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:9f:82:92:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`$ sudo ip addr add 10.1.6.207/16 dev eth6`:

```
$ sudo ip link
8: eth6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:9f:82:92:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and

```
$ ethtool eth6
Settings for eth6:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: Other
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: no
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Edit: Also tried `$ sudo ifconfig eth6 mtu 9000` which didn't do anything:

```
8: eth6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:9f:82:92:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a higher MTU, to, say, 9000 bytes instead of the default 1500? Try a "ifconfig eth6 mtu 9000" in Terminal (use sudo if you get a permission error).

Comment: I haven't tried it but I did: `$ sudo ifconfig eth6 mtu 9000`. Unfortunately it didn't change anything

Comment: You need to restart your PC with the cable out, issue the command again, make sure you don't get any error message, then plug the cable again. Those settings don't stick between reboot, unfortunately, unless you delve into your NIC settings via the ad hoc GUI and change them there, the way you can in Windows, for example. EDIT: see here for more details (http://www.microhowto.info/howto/change_the_mtu_of_a_network_interface.html)

Comment: @Didier Do you have a hint for me why increasing the MTU would suddenly enable the link on `eth6`?

Comment: Low MTUs on Gigabit Ethernet is usually a bad idea, because it causes packet fragmentation. The faster your Ethernet connection, the higher the MTU should be, provided it's an exact multiple of the default 1500 (9000 = 1500 x 6, after all). Now, this said, if your access point / router doesn't support Jumbo frames natively (the most recent all do, and auto-negotiate it with the NIC during handshake), or if it's disabled on your PC when the router expects Jumbo frames on the uplink, you're in trouble. Check if Jumbo frames are enabled on your PC, and on your router. No link handy, sorry.

Comment: @Didier But the problem I have is that I can't receive anything (no link / carrier). I don't really care about whether something is fast or slow

Comment: What kind of connection do you use? SFP+ with fiber or direct-attach? Is the carrier LED on? What is the link partner and can it see the link up?

Comment: @binaryBigInt: how come auto-negotiation is off? There must be a setting to enable it in your PC.